# Не могу программно убить ранее запущенный процесс

Tags: c#, процесс

В программе я открываю новый системный процесс, который проигрывает видео в дефолтном плеере. Стартует и играет без проблем. Потом я пытаюсь закрыть (убить) процесс и получаю ошибку: `System.InvalidOperationException: No process is associated with this object`. 
Кусок кода:

```
    string filename = "747225775.mp4";
    var myProc = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(filename)
    };
    myProc.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    try
    {
       myProc.Kill(); //Error is here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        Debugger.Break();
    }
```

Вопрос как закрыть процесс.
PS. Задаю имя файла, а не программы, чтобы использовать программу по умолчанию.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250488/cannot-kill-process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `Process.Start` связывает объект `Process` с дескриптором процесса только когда его вызов непосредственно порождает новый процесс. При передаче имени файла вместо имени программы класс `Process` обращается к функциям из *shell32.dll* и пытается определить, какие ассоциации в реестре установлены для данного расширения.

Если используется "традиционный" способ ассоциации, с вызовом командной строки и передачей имени файла первым параметром (такой используется, например, Блокнотом), вызов `Process.Start` самостоятельно создает новый процесс, и связь с дескриптором устанавливается нормально. Если же для расширения установлен более новый способ ассоциации, с вызовом специального COM-объекта (который используется многими новыми приложениями, например *Windows Media Player*), вызов `Process.Start` лишь отправляет через RPC запрос на вызов метода COM-объекта и завершается, не устанавливая связь с процессом. (Как показали исследования, непосредственное создание процесса в этом случае происходит в контексте *svchost.exe*)

Для решения этой проблемы можно использовать метод создания процесса, модифицированный следующим образом:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ProcessTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint AssocQueryString(AssocF flags, AssocStr str, string pszAssoc, string pszExtra, [Out] StringBuilder pszOut, ref uint pcchOut);

        /*Модифицированный метод создания процесса*/
        public static Process TrueProcessStart(string filename)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo psi;
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename);//получаем расширение

            var sb = new StringBuilder(500);//буфер для пути к exe-файлу
            uint size = 500;//размер буфера

            /*Получаем приложение, ассоциированное с файлом*/
            uint res = AssocQueryString(AssocF.None, AssocStr.Executable, ext,null, sb, ref size);

            if (res != 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("AssocQueryString returned error: " + res.ToString("X"));
                psi = new ProcessStartInfo(filename);//не удалось получить приложение, используем стандартный метод
            }
            else
            {
                psi = new ProcessStartInfo(sb.ToString(), filename);
            }

            return Process.Start(psi);//запуск процесса
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            string filename = "c:\\images\\clip.wmv";

            var myProc = TrueProcessStart(filename);
            if (myProc == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Process can't be killed");
                return;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            try
            {
                myProc.Kill(); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    [Flags]
    enum AssocF : uint
    {
        None = 0,
        Init_NoRemapCLSID = 0x1,
        Init_ByExeName = 0x2,
        Open_ByExeName = 0x2,
        Init_DefaultToStar = 0x4,
        Init_DefaultToFolder = 0x8,
        NoUserSettings = 0x10,
        NoTruncate = 0x20,
        Verify = 0x40,
        RemapRunDll = 0x80,
        NoFixUps = 0x100,
        IgnoreBaseClass = 0x200,
        Init_IgnoreUnknown = 0x400,
        Init_FixedProgId = 0x800,
        IsProtocol = 0x1000,
        InitForFile = 0x2000,
    }

    enum AssocStr
    {
        Command = 1,
        Executable,
        FriendlyDocName,
        FriendlyAppName,
        NoOpen,
        ShellNewValue,
        DDECommand,
        DDEIfExec,
        DDEApplication,
        DDETopic,
        InfoTip,
        QuickTip,
        TileInfo,
        ContentType,
        DefaultIcon,
        ShellExtension,
        DropTarget,
        DelegateExecute,
        SupportedUriProtocols,
        Max,
    }


}
```

Здесь для получения программы, ассоциированной с файлом, используется функция [AssocQueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Потом полученное значение передается в `ProcessStartInfo`. Однако этот метод не всегда работает, в этом случае вызывается стандартный метод. Например, для файлов изображений нет определенной программы, просто dll грузится в процесс проводника. В этом случае убить процесс просто так не получится.

Answer (score 1):

знаешь почему у тебя производится такая ошибка.
потому что когда ты этот файл стартуешь,как процесс но файл не может стартовать ся как процесс , просто у него определенно по умолчанию **(Process File exe)'Video-Media Player'** то есть Windows сохраняет эти расширение в регистре поэтому когда автоматически Кликаешь или стартуешь он автоматически стартует процесс который совпадает с этим расширением когда стартует ся файл **тогда стартует ся (Process File exe)'Video-Media Player'** а это новый Другой процесс. а у тебя находится пустой объект и поэтому ты не можешь убивать этот процесс.

вот пример.

```
        string filename = @"C:\Test\Wildlife.wmv"; 
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("wmplayer.exe", filename);
        p.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        try
        {

            p.Kill();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: автор же указал, что запускает процесс именно через файл, для запуска программы, определенной в системе по умолчанию. Если уж рекомендуете запускать с указанием программы (с чем я идеологически согласен), то уж и объясните, как определить какая программа определена пользователем по-умолчанию, иначе ответ не соответствует вопросу...

Comment: Ну просто надо узнать 'Default' процесс который совпадает с этим расширением. Я завтра отвечу на этот вопрос. у меня был ответ не полный . Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Я с таким столкнулся первый раз, когда писал приложение для контроля за RDP сессиями на ферме серверов. mstsc.exe создает головной процесс, запускает дочерний процесс с окном RDP подключения и убивает головной процесс. Таким образом, PID не может быть использован для контроля за mstsc.exe

Также точно работает 1С 8.

Выход для себя я нашел в получении всех процессов по имени exe файла, у которых командная строка соответствует определенному критерию. Вам нужно работать именно в этом направлении

Comment: Да, я так и поступил. Но это "не есть гуд"

Comment: почему это "не есть гуд"? Определить нужный процесс можно однозначно без убийства запущенных отдельно вручную

Comment: Потому, что "проигрывает видео в дефолтном плеере". Следовательно я не знаю имени exe файла.

Comment: да, myProc не дает никаких сведений о приложении. Тогда получать ассоциацию с файлом.
Взял файл .mpeg, создал файл D:\ololo.exe, сделал ассоциацию типа и программы, нашел в реестре все записи по ololo.exe
Получил HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\ololo.exe\shell\open\command, содержащий путь к приложению по умолчанию и HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.mpeg\UserChoice, содержащий ассоциацию. Дальше дело техники