# Как при выходе закрыть ранее запущенные процессы?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Есть простая программка, которая выводи лист ексель файликов, которые загружены в определенную папку. По щелчку каждый из файликов открывается в Microsoft Excel (в новом окне).

Как сделать так, чтобы при закрытии главной программы закрывались и все excel файлы, который были запущенны во время работы?

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", userAgent);
string loc = Path.GetTempPath() + @"\" + file;
client.DownloadFile(fullUrl, loc);
Process.Start(loc);
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.quit.aspx это для interop. Если по щелчку вы открываете файлы через `Process.Start`, то через объект `Process` и убивайте.

Comment: Первый раз это делаю, поэтому сразу не могу въехать как это правильно реализовать. Только что попробовал создать Process.Close(и сюда запхнуть адрес запущенного процесса, который писали в Start при вызове) но ничего не получилось.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, который у вас открывает excel-файлы, а то вслепую можно долго гадать. Под вопросом есть кнопка  [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/729104/edit)

Comment: Понятно, вы вызываете через дефолтную ассоциацию. Так можно и в OpenOffice файл открыть, если ассоциацию поправить, и даже в блокноте. Придется явно указать какой программой запускать, тогда и закрыть сможете.

Comment: и как указать какой программой открывать файл?..

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/696333/198316 похожий вопрос. Если получится немного позже напишу ответ, а вы пока изучите [это](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3) ну и связанными ссылками не брезгуйте, может и свой ответ напишете =).

Comment: ок. спасибо! сейчас буду разбираться.

Comment: На всякий случай тоже тут оставлю, вдруг пригодится https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/656244/198316