# C# Process узнать ли есть ли процесс ассоциированный с объектом

Tags: c#, процесс

Я пишу обвертку для одной программки мне нужно ее запускать из C# и прочие действия. Среди всего прочего я хотел бы иметь Property который показывал бы запущен ли процесс в данном классе или нет. Подскажите как из класса Property узнать был ли запущен процесс?

```
class MyTerminal
{
    public System.Diagnostics.Process Process { get; } = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    public IsActive
    {
    // Вот тут нужно узнать был ли ассоциирован какой либо процесс с объектом Process
    }
 public void Run()
    {
        // тут буду запускать процесс - с запуском проблемм нет. 
    }
}
```

Я ранее с процессами не работал не когда, по этому не пойму как понять был ли ассоциирован какой либо процесс с данным объектом ?

Comment: Что конкретно значит `был ли ассоциирован какой либо процесс с данным объектом`?

Comment: @tym32167 Ну мне нужно знать был ли вызван Process.Start() на нем или же нет ? Если просто инстанцировать объект то при вызове любого из свойств к примеру HasExited - выскакивает ошибка.

Comment: Как именно на нем может быть вызван Process.Start()? Я ничего не понял, возможно, будет полезно переформулировать вопрос или хотя бы примеров добавить.

Comment: @tym32167 Добавил еще один метод который у меня в классе. т.е. я буду просто вызывать Run на экземпляре своего класса для запуска моего процесса

Comment: а, я кажется понял. Сделайте процесс приватным, чтобы никто извне не имел к нем доступ. Все запуски-проверки только через ваш класс. Выход из процесса вам подскажет событие OnExit или типа того. Таким образом ваш класс будет всегда знать, был ли кем то запущен процесс и был ли из него выход, так как всё управление процессом будет происходить строго через ваш класс-обертку.

Comment: @tym32167 благодарю за совет так и сделаю

Comment: Это решение далеко не всегда сработает, см. например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/696333/Не-могу-программно-убить-ранее-запущенный-процесс . В общем случае ответ "никак" (ну, кроме приватного свойства [Associated](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,179))

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Благодарю, но рефлексию не хочу привлекать) пусть прайватное остается прайватным)) Лучше сам внутри класса буду индикатировать себе о запуске процесса